# BigQuery Dynamic SQL with Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, dynamic-sql

Recently GCP BQ supports for the dynamicSQL. I want to try this with Cloud Functions.

My BQ Dynamic SQL (which worked on UI)

```
declare cols string;
set cols=(select STRING_AGG (column_name,',') from `my_db.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` where table_name='tbla');
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE format("""select %s from `my_db.tbla`""",cols);
```

I want to pass the `table_name` value from my python code, but the thing is, will it support by Python BQ lib?

any example python code?

#### I tried these codes,  but no luck

#### Code 1:

```
def hello_gcs(event, context):
    table_name='tbla'
    client = bigquery.Client()
    job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(use_legacy_sql=False)
    sql=( '''
declare cols string;
set cols=(select STRING_AGG (column_name,',') from `my_db.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` where table_name=?);
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE format("""select @ col from `my_db.tbla`""") using cols
''',(table_name))
    query_job = client.query(sql, job_config=job_config)
    results = query_job.result()  
    for row in results:
       print("{} : {} views".format(row.url, row.view_count))
```

**Error:**

```
, line 130, in result raise self._exception google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Query error: Positional parameters are not supported at [3:104]
```

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

def hello_gcs(event, context):
    table_name='tbla'
    client = bigquery.Client()
    job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(use_legacy_sql=False)
    sql=( '''
declare cols string;
set cols=(select STRING_AGG (column_name,',') from `my_db.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` where table_name=%s);
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE format("""select @ col from `my_db.tbla`""") using cols
''',(table_name))
    query_job = client.query(sql, job_config=job_config)
    results = query_job.result()  
    for row in results:
       print("{} : {} views".format(row.url, row.view_count))
```

**Error:**

```
line 130, in result raise self._exception google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Syntax error: Illegal input character "%" at [3:104]
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: @Lak I have updated the question with the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the right syntax for this. Also notices some mistakes in my code.

#### Mistakes:

1. SQL query syntax was wrong in SQL variable(`sql=('''.......''')`)
2. The print statement in the last line was wrong, my select query doesn't have `url and view_count` columns.
3. In Dynamic SQL, we have to pass the single quote in where condition(if it is a string)

### Sample working codes:

#### Code 1:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

table_name='tbla'
client = bigquery.Client()

job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(use_legacy_sql=False)

sql="declare cols string;
set cols=(select STRING_AGG (column_name,',') 
from `my_db.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` where table_name='{}');
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE format(\"\"\"select %s from `manan.tbla` \"\"\",cols)".format(table_name)

print(sql)

query_job = client.query(sql, job_config=job_config)

results = query_job.result()
for row in results:
        print(row)
```

#### Code 2:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

table_name='tbla'
client = bigquery.Client()

job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(use_legacy_sql=False)

sql="declare cols string;
set cols=(select STRING_AGG (column_name,',')
 from `my_db.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` where table_name='{}');
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE format(\"\"\"select ? from `my_db.tbla` \"\"\") using cols".format(table_name)

print(sql)

query_job = client.query(sql, job_config=job_config)

results = query_job.result()
for row in results:
        print(row)
```

#### Code 3:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

table_name='tbla'
client = bigquery.Client()

job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(use_legacy_sql=False)

sql="declare cols string;set cols=(select STRING_AGG (column_name,',') from
`my_db.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` where table_name='{}');EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
format(\"\"\"select @ col from `my_db.tbla` \"\"\") using cols as col".format(table_name)

print(sql)

query_job = client.query(sql, job_config=job_config)

results = query_job.result()
for row in results:
        print(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Jinja2 SQL template is a better choice for building dynamic SQL. Example:

```
create or replace table {{ params.targetTable }}
as
select
    {{ params.targetColumnList|join(',') }},
    cast(null as timestamp) as begin_timestamp,
    cast(null as timestamp) as end_timestamp
from
    {{ params.sourceTable }};
```